# Unable to set Safari WebDriver options in intern config file

Tags: json, safari, intern

By default Safari WebDriver uses the `/Users/[username]/Library/Safari` location as the data directory location. This location can be overridden per 'dataDir' option on Safari WebDriver (please see this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Safari_specific))

I have tried the following ways to set this property in Intern configuration and none has been successful:

```
environments:[
{ browserName: 'safari', version: 'ANY', platform: 'MAC',
  dataDir:'/Users/[username]/Library/Safari'
//or
  'safari.options.dataDir':'/Users/[username]/Library/Safari'
//or
  'safari-option-dataDir':'/Users/[username]/Library/Safari'
  }
]
```

Please advise as to how this and other WebDriver capabilities can be set through the Intern config file in this JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for this driver, on the [configuration page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Safari_specific) you linked, are very confusing. What they are saying is that you need to put the sub-options for the driver in an object on the `safari.options` key, like so:

```
environments: [ {
  browserName: 'safari',
  version: 'ANY',
  platform: 'MAC',
  'safari.options': { dataDir: '/Users/[username]/Library/Safari' }
} ]
```